# Find a replace a value in a JSON array based on a property value with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json:

```json
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "configName": "config1",
      "configTarget": "/app/appsettings.json",
      "uid": "0",
      "gid": "0",
      "mode": 292
    },
    {
      "configName": "config2",
      "configTarget": "/app/appsettings.json",
      "uid": "0",
      "gid": "0",
      "mode": 292
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to change the value of `configName` which currently has a value of `config1`.

I know I can do

```
.configs[0].configName = "foo"
```

But I don't want to rely on the position in the array of the one I want to change, how can I find that and then set the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.configs |= map(select(.configName == "config1").configName |= "foo-bar")
```

1. Update `.configs` (`|=`)
2. `Map` over each object in the array
3. Filter (`select()`) the desired object
4. Update `.configName`

Result:

```json
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "configName": "foo-bar",
      "configTarget": "/app/appsettings.json",
      "uid": "0",
      "gid": "0",
      "mode": 292
    },
    {
      "configName": "config2",
      "configTarget": "/app/appsettings.json",
      "uid": "0",
      "gid": "0",
      "mode": 292
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SV05iO-Szwv)